# rake db:migrate - uninitialized constant WickedPdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, wicked-pdf

I'm getting the error: `uninitialized constant WickedPdf` when running rake db:migrate.

I have followed the instructions listed on this page https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/53 on how to install WickedPdf.

I can run the wkhtmltopdf binary from the command line and my wicked_pdf.rb looks like this:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

Here is my gem list for reference:

```
$ bundle exec gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.14)
actionpack (2.3.14)
activerecord (2.3.14)
activeresource (2.3.14)
activesupport (2.3.14)
brightbox (2.3.9)
bundler (1.3.5)
capistrano (2.14.2)
highline (1.6.16)
hoe (3.5.2)
hpricot (0.8.2)
htmldoc (0.2.3)
json (1.7.7)
macaddr (1.6.1)
mysql (2.9.1)
net-scp (1.1.0)
net-sftp (2.1.1)
net-ssh (2.6.7)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
paginator (1.1.1)
rack (1.1.6)
rails (2.3.14)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (4.0.1)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
rmagick (2.13.1)
systemu (2.5.2)
uuid (2.0.2)
will_paginate (2.3.16)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a PDF in a migration? have you added 'require wicked_pdf' in that migration file?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Not as far as I am aware no, it's not my app so I can't be sure though. I thought migrations were just for the DB anyway?

Comment: The link you've followed doesn't specify how to use `WickedPdf` with Rake tasks. You probably added `WickedPdf` correctly into your Rails app, but that doesn't necessarily mean that your custom Rake tasks are aware of `WickedPdf`. Try @alfonso's solution below, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just getting problems when running `rake db:migrate`, you can try wrapping the initializer with `defined?`:

```
if defined?(WickedPdf)
  WickedPdf.config = {
    :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
  }
end
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't it also mean that it won't work when the relevant piece of code is ran in the app? If db:migrate can't get run it?

Comment: @eb_dev If the app is already working, it means that WickedPdf is loaded in that environment, and therefore this hack will work. You should try it though.